# remote-debug yajsw-wrapped application with JDK>=9

Tags: java, yajsw

I'm trying to remote-debug a yajsw-wrapped application with JDK>=9.
Timeout issues aside, tt works fine with below config:

```
wrapper.java.additional.2.1=-Xdebug
wrapper.java.additional.2.2=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket\,server=y\,suspend=y\,address=*:8888
```

However I'm having issues (can't attach remote-debugger) with the assumedly equivalent below config:

```
wrapper.java.debug.port=*:8888
```

Note1: For JDK>=9, the IP address or hostname needs to be provided in front of the port # otherwise only local connections are accepted (hence the  "*:" prefix)
Note2: "wrapper.java.debug.port" option will also set friendly timeout values to allow the end-user to remote-debug without having to worry about timeout issues which is why I'm eager to use it.

Is there any way to do remote-debugging by using "wrapper.java.debug.port" option with JDK>=9 ?

Thank you very much in advance for your feedback.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

as of yajsw 12.14, after looking at the source-code, it doesn't seem possible to use wrapper.java.debug.port option to refer to a different hostname:
WrappedJavaProcess.java extract:

```
        int port = _config.getInt("wrapper.java.debug.port", -1);
        if (port != -1)
        {
            result.add("-Xdebug");
            result.add("-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address="
                    + port);
        }
```

As for timeout values, to obtain the same effect as "wrapper.java.debug.port", set following 3 values to a large number: "wrapper.startup.timeout", "wrapper.shutdown.timeout" & "wrapper.ping.timeout"